# Unable to call static methods via object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
class staticClass{
     static myMethod(){
         return 'My Method';
     }

     method2(){return 'Method 2';}
}

var s = new staticClass();
console.log(s.method2()); // 'Method 2'

console.log(staticClass.myMethod()); // 'My Method'

console.log(s.myMethod()); // 's.myMethod is not a function'
```

Why are we not able to access static methods via an object in Javascript

In Java we can access static methods via objects. They are different languages yes, but is there any reason behind this design

Comment: The whole point of the function being static is that it isn't attached to an instance. Why do you want to call it like `s.myMethod()` instead of `staticClass.myMethod()`?

Comment: Java is weird. What's the reason behind their design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call static method by `constructor` property on instance.

```js
class staticClass {
  static myMethod() {
    return 'My Method';
  }

  method2() {
    return 'Method 2';
  }
}

var s = new staticClass();
console.log(s.method2());
console.log(staticClass.myMethod());

console.log(s.constructor.myMethod());
```

Comment: it does not work for me